# Can't convert object to string in selenium

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, tostring

In document it is quite simple to do, but using selenium pack to get variable from website is problematic (as I need to now). The problem is that console.log() returns it as an object without parameters I want (that can be seen, exactly the number of clients as string/int (after removing /).

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
By = webdriver.By,
until = webdriver.until;

var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
.forBrowser('firefox')
.build();

var number;

driver.get('the website');
number = driver.findElement(By.xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[15]/td[2]')); //.toString is not working either, valueof too
console.log(number);
```

HTML of the page and string I am looking for

[image: HTML of the page (copying it to normal html code paste was taking quite long]

[image: What I see there and what number do I want]

And what I get from console.log

```
[ thenableWebDriverProxy {
    flow_:
     ControlFlow {
       propagateUnhandledRejections_: true,
       activeQueue_: [Object],
       taskQueues_: [Object],
       shutdownTask_: null,
       hold_: [Object] },
    session_:
     ManagedPromise {
       flow_: [Object],
       stack_: null,
       parent_: [Object],
       callbacks_: [Object],
       state_: 'blocked',
       handled_: true,
       value_: undefined,
       queue_: null },
    executor_: Executor { w3c: false, customCommands_: [Object], log_: [Object] },
    fileDetector_: null,
    onQuit_: [Function: onQuit],
    cancel: [Function],
    then: [Function: bound then],
    catch: [Function: bound then] },
  ManagedPromise {
    flow_:
     ControlFlow {
       propagateUnhandledRejections_: true,
       activeQueue_: [Object],
       taskQueues_: [Object],
       shutdownTask_: null,
       hold_: [Object] },
    stack_: null,
    parent_: null,
    callbacks_: null,
    state_: 'fulfilled',
    handled_: false,
    value_: 'unused',
    queue_:
     TaskQueue {
       name_: 'TaskQueue::3',
       flow_: [Object],
       tasks_: [Object],
       interrupts_: null,
       pending_: null,
       subQ_: null,
       state_: 'new',
       unhandledRejections_: Set {} } },
  [Function],
  [Function: bound then],
  [Function: bound catch],
  [Function] ]
```

Output after using console.log(number.getText());

```
ManagedPromise {
  flow_:
   ControlFlow {
     propagateUnhandledRejections_: true,
     activeQueue_:
      TaskQueue {
        name_: 'TaskQueue::3',
        flow_: [Circular],
        tasks_: [Object],
        interrupts_: null,
        pending_: null,
        subQ_: null,
        state_: 'new',
        unhandledRejections_: Set {} },
     taskQueues_: Set { [Object] },
     shutdownTask_: null,
     hold_:
      Timeout {
        _called: false,
        _idleTimeout: 2147483647,
        _idlePrev: [Object],
        _idleNext: [Object],
        _idleStart: 431,
        _onTimeout: [Function],
        _timerArgs: undefined,
        _repeat: 2147483647 } },
  stack_:
   { Task: WebElement.getText()
       at thenableWebDriverProxy.schedule (/home/soda/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:816:17)
       at WebElementPromise.schedule_ (/home/soda/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:1921:25)
       at WebElementPromise.getText (/home/soda/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:2185:17)
       at getNumber (/home/soda/main.js:15:24)
       at Object.<anonymous> (/home/soda/main.js:19:1)
       at Module._compile (module.js:573:32)
       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:582:10)
       at Module.load (module.js:490:32)
       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:449:12)
       at Function.Module._load (module.js:441:3) name: 'Task' },
  parent_: null,
  callbacks_: null,
  state_: 'pending',
  handled_: false,
  value_: undefined,
  queue_: null }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.getText() returns a promise, so in order to get the text you need to extract the value from the promise using .then();

```
number = driver.findElement(By.xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[15]/td[2]')); //.toString is not working either, valueof too

number.then(function(text){
 console.log(text); //this will log the actual text.
});
```

Answer (score 2):

`number` is `WebElement`, when you use `toString()` you get the object string, not the text. For the text use `getText()`

```
number = driver.findElement(By.xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[15]/td[2]')).getText();
console.log(number);
```

Comment: Task: WebElement.getText()
at thenableWebDriverProxy.schedule (/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:816:17)
at WebElementPromise.schedule_ (/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:1921:25)
at WebElementPromise.getText (/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:2185:17)
at getNumber (/main.js:15:24)
at Object.<anonymous> (/main.js:19:1)
at Module._compile (module.js:573:32)at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:582:10)
at Module.load (module.js:490:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:449:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:441:3) name: 'Task' },

Comment: It didn't fix anything, just that output (didn't want to edit whole post, sorry)

Comment: @Myszsoda It looks like an exception message, but it doesn't include the reason. Is this the complete message?

Comment: added to the post whole log

Comment: @Myszsoda Try `number = driver.findElement(By.xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[15]/td[2]').getText());
console.log(number);` Maybe it has to do with `console.log`

Comment: SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:545:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:582:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:490:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:449:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:441:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:607:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:382:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:137:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:497:3

Comment: @Myszsoda `driver.findElement(By.xpath('/html/body/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr[15]/td[2]')).getText();`

Comment: SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at Object.exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:76:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:545:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:582:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:490:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:449:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:441:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:607:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:382:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:137:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:497:3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135161/discussion-between-guy-and-myszsoda).